# See compiled assembly output (Visual Micro)

Tags: build, visualstudio

I'm curious about what some of my code is being compiled into, is there a way to have the compiler save the intermediate assembly files, ideally somewhere in the project folder?  I read some forum posts about holding down shift when compiling from the Arduino IDE, but even that seems pretty hackish.

Comment: Also see answer to a [compiled code size](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/11684/3917) question,  and see [Does the compiler generate intermediate assembler?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/8528),

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  I think my question is more of how though?  I can see in the Visual Micro project properties how to pass flags to the compiler, but it doesn't seem to recognize the --save-temps=obj flag.  Its probably another question but I don't know how to pass flags from the Arduino IDE either.

Comment: The 2nd post in [Assemler results, where?](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,3537.0.html) at forum.arduino.cc mentions the  -S switch and gives a batch file for Windows.  Note, probably won't apply to Visual Micro, but to set Arduino IDE to save temp files, click 'Save when Verifying or Uploading' on preferences page -- you could try both ways and see what flags get used

Answer (score 2):

Turn on Verbose Compiling in the Arduino IDE and you will see all the intermediate file names (they are done in a temporary folder).

For example:

```
/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware" -hardware "/home/nick/.arduino15/packages" -hardware "/home/nick/Arduino/hardware" -tools "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/tools-builder" -tools "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr" -tools "/home/nick/.arduino15/packages" -built-in-libraries "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/libraries" -libraries "/home/nick/Arduino/libraries" -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10607 -build-path "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp" -warnings=default -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "/tmp/arduino_1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d/sketch_mar03b.ino"
/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware" -hardware "/home/nick/.arduino15/packages" -hardware "/home/nick/Arduino/hardware" -tools "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/tools-builder" -tools "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr" -tools "/home/nick/.arduino15/packages" -built-in-libraries "/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/libraries" -libraries "/home/nick/Arduino/libraries" -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10607 -build-path "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp" -warnings=default -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "/tmp/arduino_1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d/sketch_mar03b.ino"
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch/sketch_mar03b.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" "-I/home/nick/Arduino/libraries/PID_v1" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch/sketch_mar03b.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" "-I/home/nick/Arduino/libraries/PID_v1" "/home/nick/Arduino/libraries/PID_v1/PID_v1.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" "-I/home/nick/Arduino/libraries/PID_v1" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch/sketch_mar03b.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
...
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar" rcs  "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/core/core.a" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/core/main.cpp.o"
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar" rcs  "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/core/core.a" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/core/new.cpp.o"
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc"  -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch_mar03b.ino.elf" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch/sketch_mar03b.ino.cpp.o" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/libraries/PID_v1/PID_v1.cpp.o" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/core/core.a" "-L/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp" -lm
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch_mar03b.ino.elf" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch_mar03b.ino.eep"
"/home/nick/Development/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch_mar03b.ino.elf" "/tmp/build1cdca0d02fcf3112936d1438c170697d.tmp/sketch_mar03b.ino.hex"
Using library PID_v1 in folder: /home/nick/Arduino/libraries/PID_v1 (legacy)

Sketch uses 6,484 bytes (20%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 285 bytes (13%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,763 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
```

---

Of interest are the last couple - the `xxx.elf` file and the `xxx.hex` file (where xxx is your sketch name).

The `xxx.hex` file is what is uploaded to your Arduino (well, it is decoded by Avrdude).

The `xxx.elf` file can be used to get assembly output, like this:

```
avr-objdump -Sz xxx.elf
```

That outputs to the screen. I usually output to a file:

```
avr-objdump -Sz xxx.elf > /tmp/avr_dump.txt
```

---

Example output:

```
void setup() {
      ec:   0f 93           push    r16
      ee:   1f 93           push    r17
  Setpoint = 100;
      f0:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
      f2:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
      f4:   a8 ec           ldi r26, 0xC8   ; 200
      f6:   b2 e4           ldi r27, 0x42   ; 66
      f8:   80 93 73 01     sts 0x0173, r24
      fc:   90 93 74 01     sts 0x0174, r25
     100:   a0 93 75 01     sts 0x0175, r26
     104:   b0 93 76 01     sts 0x0176, r27
  //turn the PID on
  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
     108:   61 e0           ldi r22, 0x01   ; 1
     10a:   70 e0           ldi r23, 0x00   ; 0
     10c:   82 e3           ldi r24, 0x32   ; 50
     10e:   91 e0           ldi r25, 0x01   ; 1
     110:   0e 94 04 04     call    0x808   ; 0x808 <_ZN3PID7SetModeEi>
```

In this particular  case `Setpoint` was a double so it took 8 instructions to load a literal into it.